# How to enable IsRobotDetection on a form?

Tags: sitecore-forms, recaptcha

How can I enable `IsRobotDetectipn` on the form while all the settings for below settings already enabled although I can't do that

```
Xdb.Enabled.
Xdb.Tracking.Enabled 
Analytics.AutoDetectBots.
```

[image]

Comment: What is the Sitecore version?

Comment: sitecore version is 10.1.0

Answer (score 1):

```
Robot detection for Sitecore Forms is enabled by default.
```

To enable or disable robot detection for each form field:

In the Forms designer, in the Form elements pane, on the Settings tab, select or clear the Robot detection enabled check box.

Robot detection enabled check box.

[image]

**Note :**
If you are having problems with robot detection, ensure that your layouts contain the VisitorIdentification tag: `@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()`

Comment: what do you mean with layouts and where can i find them?

Comment: You can do this in your main layout for ex mainlayout.cshtml file that should be in your view folder.

Comment: i did but not working unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

4 things are important to check :

```
Xdb.Enabled setting
Xdb.Tracking.Enabled setting
Analytics.AutoDetectBots setting
Result of XdbSettings.HasValidLicense call.
```

Make sure you have valid xDB license, for that open `/sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceAnalytics/Dashboard` url, if it opened without errors, that means that the license is valid for xDB.

In `Sitecore 10.1.0` there is no `IRobotDetection` registration in config. Instead, there is `RobotDetectionHelper` which uses the following code:

```
public static bool IsRobotDetectionAvailable => 
  Settings.GetBoolSetting("Xdb.Enabled", false) && 
  Settings.GetBoolSetting("Xdb.Tracking.Enabled", false) && 
  Settings.GetBoolSetting("Analytics.AutoDetectBots", false);
```

You may create a test page or just try it in debug to see the values of those setting in your web app and which of them is causing issues.

You can try the following url `/formbuilder/load?id=&sc_formmode=new&sc_formlang=en&sc_site=shell&_=SOME_RANDOM_VALUE` and see the source of the response. It's not easy to read it but you should see something like

```
isRobotDetectionAvailable&quot;:true,&quot;
```

or false.

If you see true in response, try a new incognito browser or potentially even recycle Sitecore.

Comment: just tried this before i asked the question and not working